# How to detect user inactivity since last touch on a particular viewcontroller in iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, user-interaction

I need to perform a particular action in a view controller when user don't touch a particular screen for 3 seconds.

How can I do that in iOS?

Answer (score 3):

Override the view's touches began method and reset a timer when you get touches.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self.timer invalidate];
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0 target:self selector:@selector(inactivityTimerFired) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

You could target the view controller instead of `self` if you need to.

Comment: its not working if i tapped or touched on a label or a tableview?

Comment: Probably because they have `userInteractionEnabled = NO`;

Comment: @jeffamaphone I think you mean `userInteractionEnabled = YES`, if user interaction is enabled, that object will intercept touches

Answer (score 1):

1. Add an `NSTimer` property/ivar to your view controller
2. Add a tap [gesture recognizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizer_basics/GestureRecognizer_basics.html) to the view you want to monitor (or use `touchesBegan:`)
3. When the tap recognizer is hit, start the timer with an interval of `3.0`s to call a function
4. If tap recognizer is hit before the function the timer calls, invalidate the timer and set it to `nil`
5. If the function that the timer was calling is hit, the user has been inactive for 3 seconds