# How do I detect user inactivity in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller, user-interaction

I need to implement an Idle Time Out feature. To do that I simply need to know how to detect when the user touches the screen (something similar to onUserInteraction method used in Android).

So how can I simply discover when the user interacts with the ViewController?

P.S: if I ask this it is because you can't find nothing good in the internet!

Comment: Just do that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26001574/how-to-detect-user-inactivity-since-last-touch-on-a-particular-viewcontroller-in

Answer (score 1):

My take is that you need to catch the event when user touches a screen. Method: touchesBegan:withEvent

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

  for touch in touches {

  // get the time measurement
  // compare it to previous one for time difference


  }

}
```

Here, Arthur Knopper has a tutorial, you may find useful: http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/drawing-circles-uitouch-ios8-swift