# how to give to activity alert in iOS swift?

Tags: ios, swift2

Suppose App is in foreground and user does not interact with app for 5 min, App should give alert.
Suppose App is in background and it remain in background for more than 5 min App should give alert as soon as app comes in foreground.

Is there any standard way to do that?

Comment: Consider the below link  for user inactivity: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27621049/how-do-i-detect-user-inactivity-in-swift and in func applicationDidEnterBackground() you can check your condition.

Comment: @BhagyalaxmiPoojary the answers on that link are not clear and specific, is there any other clear way?

Comment: Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26001574/how-to-detect-user-inactivity-since-last-touch-on-a-particular-viewcontroller-in

Comment: Here is another - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26001574/how-to-detect-user-inactivity-since-last-touch-on-a-particular-viewcontroller-in

Comment: @BhagyalaxmiPoojary Thank You, but above link i only for one viewcomtroller also it can not handle my 2nd scenario when app is in backround

Answer (score 0):

For the background part, basically you want to have a `Counter`. This `Counter` should do

- Observe `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` notification. And record the time when the selector is called. Let's say it's `lastActiveTime`.
- Observe `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` notification. And inside the selector, compare the current time with `lastActiveTime`. If it's more than 5 minutes, you'll pop up the alert.

For foreground, you could use some assumptions such as if the top most view controller is the same, assume the user hasn't interacted with the app. You can have a timer that keep checking the top most view controller.

Comment: How to compare NStimer and Int?

Comment: @sss You'll store `NSDate` and use the `compare` methods to compare two `NSDate`